# Extract primary and secondary numbers for each ID and make a JSON string

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sed, jq

I have two files as shown below: In general I will have more than three client IDs and primary and secondary numbers for each ID will be around 50-60.

#### primary.txt

```
{1=[0, 273, 546, 819], 2=[274, 1, 820], 3=[1016, 275, 821]}
```

This means client ID `1` has primary numbers `[0, 273, 546, 819]`. Similarly for other IDs.

#### secondary.txt

```
{1=[342, 1102, 608, 684], 2=[115, 191, 837, 1559], 3=[1256, 116]}
```

This means client ID `1` has secondary numbers `[342, 1102, 608, 684]`. Similarly for other IDs.

I need to read these two files, combine primary and secondary numbers for each ID, and make a JSON string like this for each ID.

#### For clientid 1

```
{"text":"for client id one.","pri":[0, 273, 546, 819],"sec":[342, 1102, 608, 684]}
```

#### For client ID 2

```
{"text":"for client id two.","pri":[274, 1, 820],"sec":[115, 191, 837, 1559]}
```

#### For client ID 3

```
{"text":"for client id three.","pri":[1016, 275, 821],"sec":[1256, 116]}
```

Is it possible to do this in shell script or Perl? I just want to print it out on the console. Below is what I have tried but I'm unable to figure out how to make proper JSON for each client ID.

```
for n in {1..3}
do
  echo "$n:"
  for f in primary.txt secondary.txt
  do
    sed -r "s/.*\b$n=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/" $f
  done
echo
done
```

Comment: Do your files really have one line each (or am I going blind)?

Comment: @zdim meaning? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: By the description it appears that `primary.txt` can only have one line? Or are there multiple (many) lines, each with `1=[...]` where the numbers differ?

Comment: Do you have command line `jq` available?

Comment: @zdim Yes it will have one line. And each `clientid=[...]` will appear once in each file.. Meaning `clientid` will appear once in primary and secondary file.

Comment: @anubhava yeah I believe so I have jq available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following script in `bash` with the help of `jq`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# convert both files to valid JSON data
sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]_]+)=/"\1":/g' primary.txt > _pri.txt
sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]_]+)=/"\1":/g' secondary.txt > _sec.txt

# loop through keys from primary and extract values from both files
while read k; do
   printf '{"text":"for client id %s.","pri":%s,"sec":%s}\n' "${k//\"/}" \
      "$(jq -c ".$k" _pri.txt | sed 's/,/& /g')" \
      "$(jq -c ".$k" _sec.txt | sed 's/,/& /g')"
done < <(jq 'keys[]' _pri.txt)

# cleanup
rm -f _pri.txt _sec.txt
```

```
{"text":"for client id 1.","pri":[0, 273, 546, 819],"sec":[342, 1102, 608, 684]}
{"text":"for client id 2.","pri":[274, 1, 820],"sec":[115, 191, 837, 1559]}
{"text":"for client id 3.","pri":[1016, 275, 821],"sec":[1256, 116]}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am getting this error: `{"text":"for client id 1.","pri":,"sec":}
./test.sh: line 10: [0,273,546,819]: command not found
{"text":"for client id 2.","pri":,"sec":}
./test.sh: line 10: [274,1,820]: command not found
{"text":"for client id 3.","pri":,"sec":}
./test.sh: line 10: [1016,275,821]: command not found`

Comment: Here is what I get `"1"
"2"
"3"`. Each line has `"1", "2" and "3"`

Comment: aah I see. let me try.. there is one spelling mistake `secondart`.

Comment: There is one more thing. Is there any way to have one space between each number in an array? I mean something like this: `[0, 273, 546, 819]` instead of like this `[0,273,546,819]`? Is this possible to do?

Comment: I really don't know why my working answer was downvoted

Comment: Presumably because the requirements specify cardinals ("one", "two") rather than numerals. Or perhaps because of the multiple invocations of jq.

Answer (score 5):

With Perl.  Data is extracted using regex, into a hash clientid => string with numbers.  Then the value is overwritten by an arrayref obtained by splitting that string. Then the two such hashes are combined into a hashref, that is converted into JSON using [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use JSON::XS;

my ($f1, $f2) = ('primary.txt', 'secondary.txt');

open my $fh, '<', $f1 or die "Can't open $f1: $!";
my %h1 = <$fh> =~ /(\d+)=\[(.*?)\]/g;
$h1{$_} = [ split /,\s*/, $h1{$_} ]  for keys %h1; 

open $fh, '<', $f2 or die "Can't open $f2: $!";
my %h2 = <$fh> =~ /(\d+)=\[(.*?)\]/g;
$h2{$_} = [ split /,\s*/, $h2{$_} ]  for keys %h2; 
close $fh;

my %client_id = ( 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three' );

for (keys %client_id) {
    my $for_json = {
        "text" => "for client id $client_id{$_}.",
        "pri" => $h1{$_},
        "sec" => $h2{$_},
    };
    my $coder = JSON::XS->new;
    my $json = $coder->encode($for_json);
    say $json;
}
```

---

If processing of both is indeed always the same put it in a subroutine

```
my ($f1, $f2) = ('primary.txt', 'secondary.txt');

my %h1 = %{ clientID_nums($f1) };
my %h2 = %{ clientID_nums($f2) };

...

sub clientID_nums {
    my ($file) = @_; 

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    my %h = <$fh> =~ /(\d+)=\[(.*?)\]/g;
    $h{$_} = [ split /,\s*/, $h{$_} ]  for keys %h; 

    return \%h;
}
```

To literally just generate (and print) the JSON string

```
say JSON::XS->new->encode($for_json);
```

or, rather, using the module's functional interface

```
say encode_json $for_json;
```

where `encode_json` is exported by default (and expects and emits UTF-8).

Comment: Do I need to install any module for this? I am working with Ubuntu btw.

Comment: @user1950349  Perhaps [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm), which is good to have, but if you don't want to just use `use JSON;` and it should work as it stands.  See the beginning of documentation for the module.

Comment: @zdim: `JSON` isn't a core module either.

Comment: @user1950349  To clarify, following Borodin's clue: if you say `use JSON;` (and later `JSON->new`) then `JSON::XS` is used if installed, otherwise `JSON::PP` gets used, a "pure-perl" implementation which I think normally gets installed with Perl (but I can't find it listed as a core module [on perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-P.html)).  The `JSON::XS` is preferred, firstly for its speed, but it does require compilation when it's installed as it's written in C ("::XS"). Another option is [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/Cpanel-JSON-XS-3.0107/XS.pm)

Comment: @user1950349  Added a little to the answer, some of which may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative Perl solution. It uses the non-core 
[`Lingua::EN::Numbers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Numbers) module
to convert from binary to English numbers. If you would rather not install this module then you can either use a simple array or keep the numbers as decimal digits

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use JSON 'to_json';
use Lingua::EN::Numbers 'num2en';

my %data;

for my $file ( qw/ primary.txt secondary.txt / ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    local $/;

    for my $item ( split /\]\s*,/, <$fh> ) {
        my ( $key, @values ) = $item =~ /\d+/g;
        push @{ $data{$key} }, \@values;
    }
}

for my $n ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ) {

    my $num = num2en($n);

    my %json = (
        text => "for client id $num",
        pri  => $data{$n}[0],
        sec  => $data{$n}[1],
    );

    print to_json( \%json, { canonical => 1 } ), "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
{"pri":["342","1102","608","684"],"sec":["342","1102","608","684"],"text":"for client id one"}
{"pri":["115","191","837","1559"],"sec":["115","191","837","1559"],"text":"for client id two"}
{"pri":["1256","116"],"sec":["1256","116"],"text":"for client id three"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions which, once the primary.txt and secondary.txt files have been converted to JSON, each require just one invocation of jq.

For the conversion to JSON, I'll assume that "=" can naively be changed to ":" -- this assumption makes it trivial to use `tr` or `sed`; I'll then use  [`any-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json) to complete the conversion, and to tie everything together, I'll use `bash`, but there are many alternatives, notably [`hjson`](http://hjson.org/users.html) as an alternative to `any-json`.

For the strings of cardinals, the first solution assumes a suitable JSON array is available, and for the sake of illustration, I'll assume this is available as a file: cardinals.json (as shown below).  The generic solution assumes that "AP-style" numbers would be acceptable.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in primary secondary ; do
      any-json --input-format=hjson <(sed 's/=/:/g' $f.txt) > $f.json
      # ALTERNATIVELY: sed 's/=/:/g' $f.txt | hjson -j > $f.json 
done

jq -s --argfile ids cardinals.json '.[0] as $p | .[1] as $s
   | range(0; $ids|length) as $ix
   | ($ix+1|tostring) as $i
   | select($p | has($i) )
   | {"text": ("for client " + $ids[$ix] + "."),
      "pri": $p[$i],
      "sec": $s[$i] }
' primary.json secondary.json
```

### Generic solution

This generic solution assumes that AP-style (Associated Press) numbers are acceptable.  It allows the keys in primary.txt to be any strings whatsoever.

```
jq -s --argfile ids cardinals.json '
    def apnumber:
      (tonumber? // null) as $i
      | if $i and $i >= 0 and $i < 10                             
        then ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"][$i]
        else .
        end;

   .[0] as $p | .[1] as $s
   | ($p|keys_unsorted[]) as $i
   | {"text": ("for client " + ($i|apnumber) + "."),
      "pri": $p[$i],
      "sec": $s[$i] }
' primary.json secondary.json
```

#### cardinals.json

Here is the output of:

```
ruby -e 'require "humanize"; 1.upto(30){|i| p i.humanize}' | jq -s
```

---

```
[
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine",
  "ten",
  "eleven",
  "twelve",
  "thirteen",
  "fourteen",
  "fifteen",
  "sixteen",
  "seventeen",
  "eighteen",
  "nineteen",
  "twenty",
  "twenty-one",
  "twenty-two",
  "twenty-three",
  "twenty-four",
  "twenty-five",
  "twenty-six",
  "twenty-seven",
  "twenty-eight",
  "twenty-nine",
  "thirty"
]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my %hash;

foreach ('primary.txt', 'secondary.txt') {
open FILE, '<', $_ or die "Could not read file $_ because $!\n";
local $/ = undef;
$hash{$_} = decode_json <FILE>;
close FILE
}

foreach (sort keys %{ $hash{'secondary.txt'}}) {
next unless
    (exists $hash{'primary.txt'}->{$_}) &&
    ('ARRAY' eq ref $hash{'primary.txt'}->{$_});

print "{\"text\":\"client id $_.\",\"pri\":[".   join(',',@{$hash{'primary.txt'}->{$_}})  ."],\"sec\":[". join(',',@{$hash{'primary.txt'}->{$_}}) ."]}\n"
}
```

Comment: The data in the input files isn't valid JSON. This program won't work. *Please  test* your solutions before posting.

Comment: Think before reply

Comment: I don't understand you. I have thought, and I have tested your code, which produces the error ***'"'expected, at character offset 1 (before "1=[342, 1102, 608, 6...")*** when fed the data in the OP's question.